# Submit button doesn't work! Clicking it doesn't even console.log

Tags: javascript, html, css, console.log, tailwind-css

I am making a landing page with tailwind css but the submit button doesn't work. I tried to check the console.log even that doesn't work!

Here is the HTML part

```
<section id="Contacts" class="text-shark-100 bg-shark-500 body-font relative">
        <div class="container px-5 pt-24 pb-15 mx-auto">
          <div class="flex flex-col text-center w-full mb-12">
            <h1 class="sm:text-3xl text-2xl font-medium title-font mb-4 text-white">Contact Us</h1>
            <p class="lg:w-2/3 mx-auto leading-relaxed text-base">Have any Feedbacks & Questions, Just Go Ahead!</p>
          </div>
          <div class="lg:w-1/2 md:w-2/3 mx-auto">
            <div class="flex flex-wrap -m-2" id="Contact">
              <div class="p-2 w-1/2">
                <input class="w-full bg-shark-400 rounded border border-shark-300 text-white focus:outline-none focus:border-red-500 text-base px-4 py-2" placeholder="First Name" id="FirstName" type="text">
              </div>
              <div class="p-2 w-1/2">
                <input class="w-full bg-shark-400 rounded border border-shark-300 text-white focus:outline-none focus:border-red-500 text-base px-4 py-2" placeholder="Last Name" id="LastName" type="text">
              </div>
              <div class="p-2 w-full">
                <input class="w-full bg-shark-400 rounded border border-shark-300 text-white focus:outline-none focus:border-red-500 text-base px-4 py-2" placeholder="Company" id="Company" type="Text">
              </div>
              <div class="p-2 w-full">
                <input class="w-full bg-shark-400 rounded border border-shark-300 text-white focus:outline-none focus:border-red-500 text-base px-4 py-2" placeholder="Email" id="Email" type="email">
              </div>
              <div class="p-2 w-full">
                <input class="w-full bg-shark-400 rounded border border-shark-300 text-white focus:outline-none focus:border-red-500 text-base px-4 py-2" placeholder="Phone Number" id="PhoneNumber" type="tel">
              </div>
              <div class="p-2 w-full">
                <textarea class="w-full bg-shark-400 rounded border border-shark-300 text-white focus:outline-none h-48 focus:border-red-500 text-base px-4 py-2 resize-none block" placeholder="Message" id="Message"></textarea>
              </div>
              <div class="p-2 w-full"><!-- Trouble of the button -->
                <button class="flex mx-auto text-white bg-red-500 border-0 py-2 px-8 focus:outline-none hover:bg-red-600 hover:shadow-2xl rounded text-lg" type="submit">Let's Talk</button>
              </div>
              <div class="p-2 w-full pt-8 mt-8 border-t border-shark-300">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
```

javascript

```
document.getElementById('Contact').addEventListener('submit', submitForm);
function submitForm(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(123)
}
```

There is not console.log or errors just nothing

Update: Thanks Got it! Changed the  to

Comment: `<div>`s do not have `submit` events. Attach a click handler to the button instead

Comment: Where is the form?

Comment: ...or make it a <form> instead.

Comment: add an id to your submit button and  try again. Also, make sure that you spell the id correctly. The event listener you posted has an undefined id.

Comment: sorry. my last comment was wrong. you need to add a form tag and use that id in the event listener.

Comment: Guys I tried the form but it breaks the design

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check out this snippet:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
            document.getElementById('contact-form').addEventListener('submit', submitForm);
            function submitForm(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                console.log('123');
            }
        });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <section id="Contacts" class="text-shark-100 bg-shark-500 body-font relative">
        <div class="container px-5 pt-24 pb-15 mx-auto">
            <div class="flex flex-col text-center w-full mb-12">
                <h1 class="sm:text-3xl text-2xl font-medium title-font mb-4 text-white">Contact Us</h1>
                <p class="lg:w-2/3 mx-auto leading-relaxed text-base">Have any Feedbacks & Questions, Just Go Ahead!</p>
            </div>
            <div class="lg:w-1/2 md:w-2/3 mx-auto">

                <div class="flex flex-wrap -m-2" id="Contact">
                    <form id="contact-form">
                        <div class="p-2 w-1/2">
                            <input class="w-full bg-shark-400 rounded border border-shark-300 text-white focus:outline-none focus:border-red-500 text-base px-4 py-2" placeholder="First Name" id="FirstName" type="text">
                        </div>
                        <div class="p-2 w-1/2">
                            <input class="w-full bg-shark-400 rounded border border-shark-300 text-white focus:outline-none focus:border-red-500 text-base px-4 py-2" placeholder="Last Name" id="LastName" type="text">
                        </div>
                        <div class="p-2 w-full">
                            <input class="w-full bg-shark-400 rounded border border-shark-300 text-white focus:outline-none focus:border-red-500 text-base px-4 py-2" placeholder="Company" id="Company" type="Text">
                        </div>
                        <div class="p-2 w-full">
                            <input class="w-full bg-shark-400 rounded border border-shark-300 text-white focus:outline-none focus:border-red-500 text-base px-4 py-2" placeholder="Email" id="Email" type="email">
                        </div>
                        <div class="p-2 w-full">
                            <input class="w-full bg-shark-400 rounded border border-shark-300 text-white focus:outline-none focus:border-red-500 text-base px-4 py-2" placeholder="Phone Number" id="PhoneNumber" type="tel">
                        </div>
                        <div class="p-2 w-full">
                            <textarea class="w-full bg-shark-400 rounded border border-shark-300 text-white focus:outline-none h-48 focus:border-red-500 text-base px-4 py-2 resize-none block" placeholder="Message" id="Message"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="p-2 w-full"><!-- Trouble of the button -->
                            <button class="flex mx-auto text-white bg-red-500 border-0 py-2 px-8 focus:outline-none hover:bg-red-600 hover:shadow-2xl rounded text-lg" type="submit">Let's Talk</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="p-2 w-full pt-8 mt-8 border-t border-shark-300">
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </section>

</body>
</html>
```

HTML `<form>` are needed to submit/send information. In the JavaScript section, first we looking for DOM Content to be loaded. On its completion I have added your code to form just created.

We have 2 options with this script, either we can add the script inside `<head>` as I have done in the snippet or we can add this script after `<form>`, in which case we don't need to check for DOM content loaded event.

Comment: This just breaks the design. I tried it already see the design break.

Comment: Thanks got it finally Changed the div to form! ❤️

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use form tag instead of section.

And I can see the id is wrong.

Should be Contacts by seeing from html template.